# How to prevent see through UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

After start using Xcode 5.0 time to time I am getting see through UITableViewCells: the previous UIViewController is visible even though which is not in the navigation stack.

- I am using `Storyboards`.
- The method `- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated` has been used.
- `TableHeaders` are not see through rather `UITableViewCells` only.

any idea...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could manage myself with the help of @Pankaj's answer but with additional piece of code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier

        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    } else {
        // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
    }
}
```

simply making only prior to iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

Not getting you correctly. But try this out.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, then in iOS 7 I am getting transparent UITableViewCells during view transition only.